# Highlight the menu item only

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to highlight each  menu item in the following drop down menu. When I hover over the current  menu with mouse it highlights the | characters also next to them. How can I solve this? Thank you for all information. 
The html code is :

```css
#menu {
  width: 960px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
#primary_nav_wrap {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  /*margin-left:50px; */
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  /*float:left;*/
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul a {
  /*display:block;*/
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  /*float:left;*/
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul li a {}
#primary_nav_wrap ul li a:after {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  content: " | ";
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul li.last a:after {
  content: none !important;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul li li.submenu a:after {
  content: none !important;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul li a:hover {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: .8;
  padding: 0;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li {
  float: none;
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a {
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
    <ul>
      <li class="currentmenuitem"><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">about us</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">day course</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="submenu"><a href="#">3 Day Course</a>
          </li>
          <li class="submenu"><a href="#">6 Day Course</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">short course</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Pasta course</a>
          </li>
          <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Pizza course</a>
          </li>
          <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Fettucine course</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Tours</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">recipes</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">reviews</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="last"><a href="#">Location</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the placement of your pseudo element from the `a` to `li`. Do this for all CSS selectors that are targeting the `a`.

Update `#primary_nav_wrap ul li a:after {}` to `#primary_nav_wrap ul li:after {}`

Below is an example of your menu with improved markup and reduced CSS (lot's of overlap of CSS properties that were not needed).

```css
#menu {
  width: 960px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul,
#primary_nav_wrap li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#primary_nav_wrap li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
#primary_nav_wrap a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
}
#primary_nav_wrap a:hover {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul > li:after {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  content: " | ";
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul > li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
}
#primary_nav_wrap .submenu > li {
  float: none;
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px;
}
#primary_nav_wrap .submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: .8;
  padding: 0;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul > li.last:after,
#primary_nav_wrap .submenu > li:after {
  content: none !important;
}
#primary_nav_wrap .submenu a {
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
    <ul>
      <li class="currentmenuitem"><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">about us</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">day course</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="#">3 Day Course</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">6 Day Course</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">short course</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="#">Pasta course</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Pizza course</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Fettucine course</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Tours</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">recipes</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">reviews</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="last"><a href="#">Location</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: But now after the last menu item LOCATION there is the | charachter and also in the dropdown submenu items there is the | charachter.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can remove them?

Comment: You were very big help!

Comment: You just have to adjust the other CSS selectors as well. I have also included a version of your menu that uses less CSS and slight modifications to the markup.

Comment: @RobertKollar please accept the answer if it solved your problem.